# Does webp images not shows on ios

Tags: ios

hi I use webp images on my wordpress site but when I open the site on ios devices the images are not showing its only work on ios 14 blow version it's not showing

Comment: Whether or not webp images display in iOS has nothing to do with WordPress, so this isn't really the place to ask. But according to https://caniuse.com/webp, its only supported on iOS 14 and up.

Comment: safari doesn't support webp until Safari v14+ or iOS 14+ see https://caniuse.com/webp